# Allow only First two and last two are alphabets and rest in between are numeric(e.g EE123456789IN) in text box

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, validation

Hey I am trying to validate a textbox for getting first two and last two char are alphabets and rest of are numeric in between in the length of 13. eg EE123456789IN .   How to validate this in textbox and also check this on submit button.`

```
function Validate_Post() {
  var tb = document.getElementById("<%=txt_SpeedPost.ClientID%>").value;
  var a = tb.charAt(0);
  var b = tb.charAt(1);
  var c = tb.charAt(11);
  var d = tb.charAt(12);

  if ((a != 'E' && b != 'E') || (c != 'I' && d != 'N') || d != 'N') {
    alert("Invalid Speed Post Ref. No The Speed Post Ref No must be like this EE123456789IN") enter code here
  }

  for (var i = 3; i < 11; i++) {
    if ((tb.charAt(i) >= 48 && tb.charAt(i) <= 57) || (tb.charAt(i) >= 96 && tb.charAt(i) <= 126)) {
      alert("Enter Number after EE e.g EE123456789IN")
    }
  }
  return true
}


<asp:Button ID="Btn_submit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" align="center" Width="168px " OnClick="Btn_submit_Click" OnClientClick="Validate_Post();"  style="font-weight: 700"/>
```

I want result like this that textbox should validate e.g EE123456789IN and max length should be 13 and textbox only accepts this kind of input. if not then it will show error during submit. can you help me out of this.

Comment: C#: `bool ok = text.StartsWith("EE") && text.EndWith("IN");`. You condition seems to be a bit undecided about the ands and ors.. ((Also: In non-Indian English  an alphabet is a __set__ of characters not a single one! SO is a non-Indian English site))

Comment: Are you `Kharoti`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use below code and let me know if you face any issue or you need any change in it.

```
  SpeedPost: 
  <asp:TextBoxID="txt_SpeedPost" runat="server" maxlength=13 />
  <asp:Button ID="Btn_submit" runat="server" Text="SUBMIT" align="center" Width="168" 
  OnClick="Btn_submit_Click" OnClientClick="return Validate_Post();"  style="font- 
  weight: 700"/>

  <script>
  function Validate_Post() {
   var tb = document.getElementById("<%=txt_SpeedPost.ClientID%>").value;
   var length = tb.length;
   var first2 = tb.substr(0, 2);
   var last2 = tb.substr(length - 2, length);
   //alert(first2 + '::' + last2);

    var isAlphabet = allLetter(first2+last2);
   //if(first2 != 'EE' || last2 != 'IN')
    if(!isAlphabet)
   {
     alert("Invalid Speed Post Ref. No The Speed Post Ref 
       No must be like this EE123456789IN"); 
     return false;
   }

   var centerLength = length - first2.length - last2.length;
   var centerChars = tb.substr(2, centerLength);
   //alert(centerChars);
   if (isNaN(centerChars)) 
   {
    // not a number
      alert('not a number');
      return false;
   }

   return true;
   }


   function allLetter(inputtxt)
   {
      var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
       if(inputtxt.match(letters))
       {
          return true;
        }
       else
        {
            return false;
         }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thx a lot for help ,,,, and  I still have a issue with this function allLetter(inputtxt)
   {
      var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
       if(inputtxt.value.match(letters))
       {
          return true;
        }
       else
        {
            return false;
         }
    }                                                                                                                                                      rest of the code working fine

Comment: Sorry I didn't test this much of code, let me correct it and update it

Comment: Hello, I updated allLetter() method with a small change, please check it and let me know if you still face any issue.
If this solution helps or resolves your issue then upvote and mark it as correct answer please.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ASP.NET, but you can do it with pure HTML without Javascript

```
<form action='/somewhere' method='post'>
  <input type='text' pattern='[A-Z]{2}\d{9}[A-Z]{2}' required />
  <input type='submit' />
</form>
```